# How to achieve flex fade effect show time and hide time are different but consecutive

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I trying to implement fade effect in flex. I implemented a fade effect such that every 10 seconds I take the implement of visibility. So its alpha takes 10 sec from 0 to 1 and 1 to 0. What I want to achieve is I want to have `showfade` for 10 seconds and 5 seconds for `hidefade` effect. How can I achieve this?

My fade effects:

```
<s:Fade id="showFade" alphaFrom="0" alphaTo="1" duration="10000"  target="{rssTextRichText}"/>
<s:Fade id="hideFade" alphaFrom="1" alphaTo="0" duration="10000" target="{rssTextRichText}"/>
```

My rich text:

```
<s:RichText id="rssTextRichText"  x="{(mainContainer.width/1920)*60}" y="{(mainContainer.height/1200)*90}" 
fontWeight="bold" fontSize="15" color="0x787878"                    
width="{(mainContainer.width/1920)*435}" height="{(mainContainer.height/1200)*240}"  verticalAlign="top" visible="false" showEffect="{showFade}" hideEffect="{hideFade}">                                   
</s:RichText>
```

My interval and toggle method to start effects:

```
var rssInterval:uint = setInterval(rssChanged, 10000);

public function rssChanged():void{

                rssTextRichText.visible = !rssTextRichText.visible;     
                setRSSLabel();
                rssTextRichText.visible = !rssTextRichText.visible;

            }
```

As i said I want to have showFade for 10 seconds and hideFade for 5 seconds. After hideFade,I want showFade to start immediately and not wait for 5 seconds.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is as follows: (Additionally first trigger should be given at the desired application location)

```
<s:Fade id="showFade" alphaFrom="0.5" alphaTo="1" duration="20000"  target="{rssTextRichText}" 
                effectEnd="showFade_effectEndHandler(event);" effectStart="showFade_effectStartHandler(event);"/>
        <s:Fade id="hideFade" alphaFrom="1" alphaTo="0" duration="1000" target="{rssTextRichText}" 
                effectEnd="hideFade_effectEndHandler(event);" effectStart="hideFade_effectStartHandler(event);"/>


    protected function showFade_effectStartHandler(event:EffectEvent):void
    {

        setRSSLabel();
        //testArea.text+="showFade effect start\n";


    }

    protected function hideFade_effectStartHandler(event:EffectEvent):void
    {

        //testArea.text+="hideFade effect start\n";

    }

    protected function showFade_effectEndHandler(event:EffectEvent):void
    {

        //testArea.text+="showFade effect end\n";               
        rssTextRichText.visible = !rssTextRichText.visible;

    }

    protected function hideFade_effectEndHandler(event:EffectEvent):void
    {

        //testArea.text+="hideFade effect end\n";       
        rssTextRichText.visible = !rssTextRichText.visible;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, first set your hideFade duration to 5000 (5 seconds)

```
<s:Fade id="hideFade" alphaFrom="1" alphaTo="0" duration="5000" target="rssTextRichText}"/>
```

For the second part, you want to stop the hide-effect if it's on and start showing the showFade effect from that point, you can capture the EffectEvent.EVENT_START, stop the hide  effect and start showing the showFade-effect:

```
function foo_handleEffectStart(e:EffectEvent):void {
 if(e.target == "showFade") {
   hideFade.stop();
   showFade.start(); // dunno if this is necessary or if the event starts anyway. 
 }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. How does the handle effect start called, where do i bind it?

Comment: Oh yeah, bind it to your <S:Fade>  <s:Fade id="showFade" alphaFrom="0" alphaTo="1" duration="10000"  target="{rssTextRichText}" effectStart="showFade_handleEffectStart(event)/>

Comment: In the if statement does e.target returns rssTextRichText ?

Comment: Ah right, then in your handleEffectStart the e.target should be "== rssTextRichText"